# How to pass texture through two shaders?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0

All I need is to pass texture through fragment shader 1, get the result and pass it to fragment shader 2.

I know how to link vertex and fragment shader together into a program and get the shader object.

I don't know how to get the result of shader 1, switch the shaders (`GLES20.glUseProgram` ?) and pass the result of shader 1 to shader 2.

Any ideas how to do it?

**UPDATE**
This is an example what I want to achive

**Effect 1:**

[image]

**Effect 2:**

[image]

My goal is to combine Effect 1 and Effect 2.
**UPDATE 2**

*effect 2 function:*

```
...    
    uniform float effect2;

    vec2 getEffect_() {
        float mType = effect2;
        vec2 newCoordinate = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, textureCoordinate.y);
        vec2 res = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, textureCoordinate.y);

        //case 1
        if(mType==3.5) {
            if (newCoordinate.x > 0.5) {
                res = vec2(1.25 - newCoordinate.x, newCoordinate.y); }
        }
        else
        //case 2
        ...

        return res;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the result as a texture to another shader, you should use RTT(render to texture) so that you can get a texture to pass to another shader.

Yes, you should use  glUseProgram(name) to switch another shader but not only this, you should render it at the original FBO(now you use)

1. make one FBO to make the result as a texture.
2. render to texture using the first shader then you can get a texture
3. Draw the texture with the second shader at the main fbo(now you use)

If you just want to combine two effect, just combine the two fragment shaders.

```
//At the end of the second frag shader
// skip this below
//gl_FragColor = result;
// put these codes 
 float grayScale = dot(result.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
 gl_FragColor = vec4(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale, 1.0);
```

Only use one shader program with the second effect fragment shader.

I will assume you don't need to show those 30 effects at once.

1. define `uniform float effect2` in the 10 fragments like effect1.
2. pass the effect2 like 0.5, 1.5 or 2.5
3. according to the value you pass, differently mix the effect.
   For example,

   > ```
   > if(effec2>2.0) {
   >         float grayScale = dot(result.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
   >          gl_FragColor = vec4(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale, 1.0); 
   >     } else if(effect2>1.0) {
   >         vec3 final_result_of_effec2_2 = fun_2(result.rgb);
   >          gl_FragColor = vec4(final_result_of_effec2_2, 1.0); 
   >     } else {
   >           vec3 final_result_of_effec2_3 = fun_3(result.rgb);
   >          gl_FragColor = vec4(final_result_of_effec2_3, 1.0); 
   >     }
   > ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you see the updated question?
Is your solution useful in this case?

Comment: @VitaliGrabovski That is a simple problem. In short, you don't need two shader programs, FBOs and even RTT. The answer is updated now.

Comment: What if there are 10 fragment shaders like effect 1 and 3 shaders like effect 2? Do I need to create 30 shaders to cover all cases?

Comment: @VitaliGrabovski I am saying that you need only one shader program(one vert shader + one frag shader) because the effects can be combined in one fragment shader

Comment: @VitaliGrabovski if all 10 frag shaders are same and another 3 frag shaders are same too, just make two. It is good to assume one effect is one shader in this case.

Comment: They aren't. First 10 effects (shader programs) are just similar to effect 1. But they have differences. Other three are similar to effect 2.
So this is an opportunity to have 10*3=30 different effects.
That is why I need to receive the result of one of first 10 effects and pass it to one of another 3 effects. 
I just do not want to create 30 separated shader programs to cover all cases.

Comment: @VitaliGrabovski I updated. In any cases, you don't need 30 shader programs lol

Comment: Thanks for convince me to combine effect1 and effect2 directly in fragment shader.
It works fine. 
I have another question you may give an advice. There is the same function (see update 2) in every fragment shader of ten effect1-like shaders. This function implements effect 2 depend on effect2 variable as you suggested.
Is it possible to write getEffect_() in one place, not in every shader where it is using?

Comment: @VitaliGrabovski shaders can't share a function although it seems to be able to be combined all shader codes you wrote.  Try to combined all codes, and display each effect using variables